# Select all text but HTML Tags

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Been trying to figure this out for a while, came across this `(<[^>]*>)` which helped me select all html tags, my objective is to use regex to help me select anything but HTML tags.. i tried to negate this but couldnt figure it out..

Apprecaite your help

here's an example, so in summary i would like to select all but html tags..

```
<br>
<font size="2" face="Arial">&nbsp Bla Bla Bla</font>
<br>
<font size="2" face="Arial">More Bla Bla Bla</font> <br>
<br>Some more bla bla bla<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Split with `<[^>]*>`.

Comment: What language are you using? If PHP, use strip_tags or, better, DOMDocument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text from HTML markup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137065/extract-text-from-html-markup)

Comment: i am using this website to simulate it.. and none of the available solutions solves my problem.. not the ones i've looked at so far http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work

```
(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=<)
```

or if you only want text between opening and closing tags

```
 (?<=>)[^<>]+(?=(<\/))
```

but the second one fails at `<br>Some more bla bla bla<br>`

"<" and ">" inside your string will screw almost every regex up.

You should use a Dom-Parser instead of Regex

Comment: What about: `<p> A > B</p>`?

Comment: @Toto: that would be a problem. :D

Comment: it did actually!!! thanks a lot!!! would you by any chance know why it didnt work on the one i was using? any other formats to achieve the same?

Comment: @Raeef at regexr.com the error says "lookbehind is not supported at javascript"